# How to fix wrong mount of Ubuntu OS

Tags: mount

I'm running a dual boot machine with Windows and Ubuntu.  I have several drives as well and yesterday I was trying to mount them in the Disks app because I was was having write problems to them.

My problem is that I ended up making a change to the mount location of Ubuntu, once I boot up to the Grub and select Ubuntu it doesn't boot.  I booted up via the Ubuntu installation USB and tried using Boot Repair but that didn't work.  I used the commands in https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/ :

```
sudo fdisk -l

sudo blkid
```

to identify where Linux/Ubuntu is located and try to match things up.  I got stuck down a rabbit hole with it saying I already had the partition mounted, then I was spending too much time trying to unmount a busy device .

Is there an easier method to fix mounting problem? I don't want to reinstall.

/etc/fstab file is located here in pastebin because the # was messing formatting

https://pastebin.com/FABwbkmv

```
sudo fdisk -l 

/dev/nvme0n1p1 *         2048 819202047 819200000 390.6G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/nvme0n1p2      819202048 820252671   1050624   513M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/nvme0n1p3      820254718 976771071 156516354  74.6G  5 Extended
/dev/nvme0n1p5      820254720 976771071 156516352  74.6G 83 Linux




ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo blkid
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="F2F8316FF8313369" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="305b58f8-01"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="8AC5-7530" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="305b58f8-02"
/dev/nvme0n1p5: UUID="2c6252b2-98d8-4da8-87ee-60471a0d6a65" TYPE="ext4" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="305b58f8-05"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="FeidhmchlM-CM-!ir" UUID="FE5A160E5A15C475" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="2824c2e8-01"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="1TB HDD" UUID="4C6A12C86A12AF28" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="57ec112b-01"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="UBUNTU 20_0" UUID="04DB-A1EB" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="001886ee-01"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sdd1: LABEL="2TB HDD" UUID="4C10D99910D989FA" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="3622d19f-050f-460c-8bcf-e3e14333fdff"
/dev/sde1: LABEL="SANDISK32GB" UUID="52DF-6084" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="001035b8-01"
```

fdisk seems to show the same partition as two partitions (/dev/nvme0n1p3 & /dev/nvme0n1p5 )

** EDIT **

I'm having problems editing /etc/fstab... I tried mounting with

```
mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdc1 /
```

but the fstab file is still readonly

Comment: You will need to post your /etc/fstab file along with your drives (`lsblk -f`) if you want someone to look at the specifics to repair your situation.

Comment: Ok, Can I edit and save the /etc/fstab file from a recovery USB?

Comment: Of couse you need to supply the fstab of your broken system, under "etc" on the partition that contains root of the broken system.

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help... I used the solution by Daveh0 to get access to the fsab file:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/185026/how-to-edit-etc-fstab-when-system-boots-to-read-only-file-system?newreg=5c60a16d6cfe4ed0a64231b59d5a6e98

> Highlighted 'Ubuntu' at the boot menu
>
> hit 'e' to edit the configuration
>
> in the line starting with linux=, I switched the 'ro' to 'rw' and
> added the word 'single' at the very end of the line
>
> hit f10 to boot
>
> once it booted, as root, I did:
>
> mount -o remount,rw

It booted up with a recovery prompt so I could execute

```
nano /etc/fstab
```

and inserted a line

```
UUID=2c6252b2-98d8-4da8-87ee-60471a0d6a65 /  ext4 errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

after that it booted up - just have to get read write access to the drives.

**EDIT**

I got the external drives mounted by following steps:

Listed disks and partitions with the following:

```
lsblk | grep sd
```

Identified which drives were SSD & mechanical:

```
lsblk -o +ROTA | grep sd
```

Created some local folders to try and mount the drives by hand:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/HDD1

sudo mkdir /mnt/HDD2

sudo mkdir /mnt/SSD
```

Mount the drives to the folders:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/HDD1

sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/HDD2

sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/SDD
```

Checked the mounts to see if it worked:

```
lsblk -o +ROTA | grep sd[a-c]1
```

I tried copying a file to each drive and it worked so next step was the fstab file and making it permanent.  I used the mtab file to get the details of the current mounted drives (very useful):

```
cat /etc/mtab | grep sd[b-c]1
```

Then to determine the partitions UUID I used:

```
blkid | grep sd[b-c]1
```

In order to edit the fstab file i had to go

```
sudo -i
```

and then

```
vim /etc/fstab
```

I ended up with the following fstab, there is a lot of parameters than you can added but its important to follow the mtab file because it has demonstrated that read write works.

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=2c6252b2-98d8-4da8-87ee-60471a0d6a65 /          ext4      errors=remount-ro 0    1
#
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=8AC5-7530 /boot/efi  vfat       defaults         0       1
#
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
#
# NTFS Mounts - 500GB SSD
UUID=FE5A160E5A15C475 /media/Feidhmchláir ntfs-3g rw,relatime,locale=ga_IE.utf8 0 0 
#
# NTFS Mounts - 1TB HDD
UUID=4C6A12C86A12AF28 /media/1TB ntfs-3g rw,relatime,locale=ga_IE.utf8 0 0
#
# NTFS Mounts - 2TB HDD
UUID=4C10D99910D989FA /media/2TB ntfs-3g rw,relatime,locale=ga_IE.utf8 0 0 
#
```

Full Article can be found here:
https://www.howtogeek.com/444814/how-to-write-an-fstab-file-on-linux/

Comment: Your posted fstab was completely blown out. Your fstab in your answer is almost a complete copy of my answer... except for the specific NTFS mounts, for which I gave examples.

Comment: thanks for posting your answer but in the end it didn't fix my problem.  I couldn't boot in the beginning and I fixed that using an answer to another question in this forum (link above), then you posted your answer and the only thing you added was using UUID but I tried your answer but I didn't have write access to the drives.

Comment: That's not correct. Your original fstab didn't have root or efi mounts. I wrote my fstab from scratch. You used my EXACT fstab, and you just modified some specific mount options for the NTFS drives... for which I had given examples.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm a relatively new user to Ubuntu and Linux and I didn't understand the process of how to go through and mount drives.  I'm signing on this thread now, best regards

Answer (score 1):

re: *"fdisk seems to show the same partition as two partitions (/dev/nvme0n1p3 & /dev/nvme0n1p5 )"*

Incorrect. /dev/nvme0n1p3 is an **extended** partition, and /dev/nvme0n1p5 is a **logical** partition inside of /dev/nvme0n1p3.

---

re: *"mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdc1 /"*

/dev/sdc1 would be the wrong partition to change to rw. You'd want /dev/nvme0n1p5. Do it with `sudo mount -o remount,rw /`. Note that for Ubuntu 18.04 and higher, the boot disk is already mounted r/w in Recovery Mode.

---

Start with this /etc/fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
#
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=2c6252b2-98d8-4da8-87ee-60471a0d6a65 /  ext4 errors=remount-ro  0       1
#
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=8AC5-7530 /boot/efi  vfat       defaults         0       1
#
/swapfile     none            swap    sw              0       0
#
# NTFS mounts (examples, using UUID=)
#UUID=4C6A12C86A12AF28 /media/1TB ntfs-3g    defaults,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=30       0       0
#UUID=4C10D99910D989FA /media/2TB ntfs-3g    defaults,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=30       0       0
```

**Note:**

Add additional NTFS partitions using UUID= (instead of label names) as required, and don't mount your Windows C: drive partition.

See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions) for additional help information.

Comment: I'm still having trouble not being able to write to the external Hard Disks.

Comment: That's a little different problem than your question asks. If you're talking about the NTFS disks, 1TB and 2TB, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions

Comment: Also see https://help.ubuntu.com/search.html?cof=FORID%3A9&cx=003883529982892832976%3Ae2vwumte3fq&ie=UTF-8&q=mounting+ntfs&sa=Search